# Userform opening on wrong workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I have a userform that has a command button to open another userform.  This works well most of the time but there is a particular scenario where it does not work at all.

The users of said userforms typically work on multiple monitors and also have multiple workbooks open. These other workbooks are not associated with my workbook.

If the user is working in another workbook on monitor 1 and then clicks the button to open the secondary userform on monitor 2, the secondary userform opens on monitor 1 and behaves like it's parent is the other workbook.  To correct this behavior, the user needs to click a cell on monitor 2's workbook and then click the button to open the secondary userform.  So it seems to be a workbook activation issue but this is not the case.

I have tried different methods of activating the correct workbook before showing the secondary userform with code to no avail.

Here's the basic code I use to launch the secondary userform when the button is clicked:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    With UserForm2
        .StartUpPosition = 0
        .Left = Application.Left + (0.5 * Application.Width) - (0.5 * .Width)
        .Top = Application.Top + (0.5 * Application.Height) - (0.5 * .Height)
        .Show vbModeless

    End With

End Sub
```

I found this thinking I just need to explicitly set the userforms parent window before showing it but the userform will not open at all with this code:
http://www.cpearson.com/excel/SetParent.aspx

I hope this makes sense.  It's kind of hard to explain.

Comment: The form is modeless, so I'm confused as to what you mean by "parent window". Is it just an issue with positioning the form?

Comment: what does "and behaves like it's (sic) parent is the other workbook" mean exactly? Also that `With` block is bloody misleading, once you realize that `With New` witholds an object reference that gets destroyed at `End With` (i.e. if you change your code to `With New`, form will be destroyed as soon as it's shown).

Comment: No, not an issue with positioning the form.  If you click the 'other workbook' on the task bar, the secondary userform gets focus.  I should click my workbook on the taskbar and the secondary userform should get focus. It goes like this:
Open my userform on monitor 2>
Open other workbook on monitor 1>
Click a cell on monitor 1 workbook>
Now click button to open secondary userform on monitor 2>
Secondary userform will open on monitor 1 instead of monitor 2>
Clicking the other workbook on the task bar will give secondary userform focus indicating that its parent is the other userform

Comment: Feel free to [edit] your original question to clarify :)

Comment: I'm currently at home with no access to dual monitors otherwise I could maybe do a screen recording to show what I mean.  I apologize :(

Comment: I think I replicated the behavior you're talking about. Do you have a reference to the correct workbook available when the form is being shown?

Comment: Thanks @Comintern  I created a simple workbook with 2 userforms just for an example.  Userform1 has a button to open Userform2.  Follow the steps in my first comment and you should be able to recreate it.

Comment: @Comintern I'm not entirely sure what you mean. I have tried this:
    ThisWorkBook.Activiate 
inside the with statement

Comment: Right, but the question was whether you have the correct `Workbook` object available when you call `CommandButton1_Click()`. Like `Public theWBImTalkingAbout As Workbook`.

Comment: I do have a global variable called g_workbook that references my workbook but how do I use that when showing a userform?

Comment: My apologies to everyone again.  It's very hard to explain with just text and the userform works great regardless.  It's just gives the appearance of being unprofessional when the user has windows popping up across random monitors.

Comment: No worries - if it's any consolation, half the time my Remote Desktop session authenticates on one monitor, and opens on the other. It's not sloppy coding on your part.

Comment: I was having a similar problem and found this post. It was somewhat helpful. Some testing revealed that the controls in a modeless UserForm refer to the currently ActiveWorkbook  and not the Workbook that created the modeless UF. Including a "ThisWorkbook.Activate" at the top of the CommandButton event handler changed the focus back to the workbook that created the modeless UF and drew the UF in that sheet.  I hope this helps. Yes, this is hard to explain.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a reference to the `Workbook` that you want to set the form's parent to, you only need the two window handles to pass to [`SetParent`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setparent).  For the `Workbook`, you can simply use your `g_workbook` variable to get it's `Window`, which exposes an `Hwnd` property.

For the `UserForm`, you'll need to use a second API call ([`FindWindow`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-findwindowa)). Just pass it the caption of your window (and optionally the class if you're worried about it not being unique) and it returns its window handle. Put this in the declarations at the top of the module:

```
#If VBA7 Then
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function SetParent Lib "user32" ( _
        ByVal hWndChild As Long, _
        ByVal hWndNewParent As Long) As Long

    Private Declare PtrSafe Function FindWindow Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowA" _
        (ByVal lpClassName As String, _
        ByVal lpWindowName As String) As Long
#Else
    Private Declare Function SetParent Lib "user32" ( _
        ByVal hWndChild As Long, _
        ByVal hWndNewParent As Long) As Long

    Private Declare Function FindWindow Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowA" _
        (ByVal lpClassName As String, _
        ByVal lpWindowName As String) As Long
#End If
```

Then, make the call to `SetParent` before you show the form:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    With New UserForm2
        .StartUpPosition = 0

        Dim host As Window
        Set host = g_workbook.Windows(1)
        'You can also calculate these on the host position if you want.
        .Left = Application.Left + (0.5 * Application.Width) - (0.5 * .Width)
        .Top = Application.Top + (0.5 * Application.Height) - (0.5 * .Height)

        Dim handle As Long
        handle = FindWindow(vbNullString, .Caption)
        SetParent handle, host.Hwnd

        .Show vbModeless
    End With
End Sub
```

As you speculated in the question, this seems to work at sorting the focus out. Whether or not it is *stable* is a different question - it's conceivable that if you set the parent to the wrong workbook that closing the new parent workbook could cause unintended behavior.

Comment: Thanks @Comintern  This looks interesting.  I will try it tomorrow when I get to my desk and accept this answer if I can get this to work.  Thank you all for your time and if anyone else has some suggestions they are very welcome.

Comment: This worked but with some strange side effects.  None of the comboboxes on the secondary userform will populate (the code to populate the comboboxes runs but nothing updates on the window).  Gonna play around with this idea a bit more.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to make sure the Form is unloaded before activating your workbook.

From your Command button:

1. Unload MyForm
2. MyWorkbook.Activate
3. Load MyForm
4. MyForm.Show

Comment: I can confirm that this approach works. It seems that a newly created Userform takes the most recently opened Workbook as parent. So, it was sufficient to instantiate a new Userform after the Workbook had loaded.